# WCF service is not getting called

Tags: wcf

I have a web solution and I have a WCF service project inside it. We need to support "cookieless". so in the web.config, it's set as

```xml
 <sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer"
    sqlConnectionString="Data Source=ds;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=uid;Password=pwd" 
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
    cookieless="true" 
    timeout="720" 
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"/>
```

The WCF service will be supporting sessions, so we have also set "aspNetCompatibilityEnabled" to true in web.config.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

The service and interfaces are as follows,

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface ICDOCService
{ }

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CDOCService : ICDOCService
{ }
```

The problem we are facing is we cannot access the service from any client application. (web app, WCF test client)

The following error is showing, when we access it via WCF Test client,

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> The content type `text/html`; `charset=UTF-8` of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the `IsContentTypeSupported` method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
<HTML>

 <HEAD>

 <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="http://localhost:53721/Services/CDOCService.svc?disco"/>

  <STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; 

  MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; 

  FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 

  12px; 

  COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; 

  PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; 

  PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 

   1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: 

   Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 

   15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 

   3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; 

   FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}
 </STYLE>

<TITLE>CDOCService Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><DIV id="content"><P '.



Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ICDOCService.GetCDOCCount(String institutionID, String mrnID, String userID, String callingSystemID, String securityToken)
   at CDOCServiceClient.GetCDOCCount(String institutionID, String mrnID, String userID, String callingSystemID, String securityToken)
```

Comment: When you are cookieless, the URL gets modified and has the session ID put into it.  I wonder if that is causing the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the response. When we set "either" cookieless to "false" or "aspNetCompatibilityEnabled" to "false", the service "can" be called. But both these 2 are needed since from the service we need to access session values, and we need to support cookieless.

Comment: What you said was true. Since the url is getting changed, the service cannot be called, but these 2 settings are also needed :(

Comment: Sounds like you have mutually exclusive requirements.  Is there another way you can access the needed informatoin without using Session, if you absolutely can't use cookies?  Maybe a persistent data store (like a table in the database)?

Comment: Thanks Tim for your suggestions. Yes we finally chose to remove "aspNetCompatibilityEnabled" and to use a different storage or to pass relevant information as a parameter to the service. Thank you for your time!

Comment: you can also use **Service Trace viewer tool** to check the real exception at service side.

Comment: @Tim you should consider posting that as an answer (not in the least because it seems the OP went with your suggestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer per @Jeroen's suggestion, as it seemed to help the OP.

Sounds like you have mutually exclusive requirements. Is there another way you can access the needed informatoin without using Session, if you absolutely can't use cookies? Maybe a persistent data store (like a table in the database)?